# Undefined error in email function for Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an email function which looks fine but giver error as below "Invalid email: undefined (line 2, file "Code")"

It should run and execute without error.

```
function sendEmail(to,subject,msg) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,msg)
}

function testEmail(){
  sendEmail ("abhishek@example.com", "The Subject", "Hi this is a test mail")
}

function getSheetByName(name){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var n in sheets){
    if (name==sheets[n].getName()){
      return sheets[n];
    }
  }
  return sheets[0];
}

function prepareMessage(name) {
  var sheet = getSheetByName("Msg");
  var oldSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet)
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1)
  data = dataRange.getValues()
  var msg = data[0][0]
  msg = msg.replace("%FIRST%",name) //Not using any name for RollColl
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(oldSheet)
  return msg
}


function sendNotification(){
  var sheet = getSheetByName("testRollcallremaining")
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var cols = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2,3,rows-1,cols)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data){
    var name = data[i][0]
    var to = data[i][1]
    // sendEmail(to, "Process Update Rollcoll Pending","People failing to acknowledge the 
    // roll call within 24 hours needs to share the challenge they are facing in doing so.
    // In case the instructions are not clear, a clear email needs to go out to Rukhiya with 
    // me/Saran in CC after clicking the 'No, I haven't understood. Need assistance!' option. 
    // Else, it will be considered as an action of negligence.")

    var msg = prepareMessage(name)
    sendEmail(to,"Roll Coll Pending",msg)
  }
}
```

There should not be any error, it is sending email when used this function in code but showing as error and getting failed msg notification from google sheet.

Comment: That sounds like the value of the variable / argument `to` is undefined at the time of execution. Where is the function `sendEmail` called? Can you please include that code, and how it populates the argument `to` as it calls the function? Your included code, as-is, is not enough to diagnose the issue.

Comment: As @JoshuaT has mentioned, 'to' needs to be defined as a string containing the email address to send the email to. Where is `sendEmail` being called from, and where are the variables being taken from? If you're using Sheets then it could be that the values are being taken incorrectly. Have you tried using `Logger.log(to)` before `GmailApp.sendEmail(to,subject,msg)`?

Comment: Hi @JoshuaT and RafaGuillermo, I have added whole  code which I am using.

Comment: Delete the function called `sendEmail`. (Lines one, two and three)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Why have you defined the `sendEmail()` function at all? It's completely redundant as it just passes the same variables along to  `GmailApp.sendEmail()` which you can just call in the first place?

Comment: I ran `testEmail()` in my test environment without any issue too, the issue appears to be coming from either `var to = data[i][1]` or ` var msg = prepareMessage(name)`. What is the output of `Logger.log(typeof data[i][1]);` and `Logger.log(typeof name);` if you run htem the line before `sendEmail(to,"Roll Coll Pending",msg)` in `sendNotification()`? Also remember to include `;` at the end of each line so your script is read correctly.